# problem when restarting apache by updating php code

Tags: php, apache, centos

Good evening friends, I need your help since I have a problem with a webservice mounted in centos 6.9 with the version of apache 2.2.15 and php 5.5.38.

Before when doing any code I only loaded it and it worked immediately, I had a vacation and a partner of the work made a modification to that server that now every time you update a file, it is required to restart the apache so that you can apply the changes

Currently the partner does not work in the company and I need to replace the apache as it was by default.

They have some idea of ​​how to solve this problem.

Thank you for your cooperation

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the [opcache extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php) enabled.

You can remove the extension or tell opcache to check your file for changes every time its loaded by adding

`opcache.revalidate_freq=0` your php config

Answer (score 0):

[info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vrr8.jpg)

check the php.ini and the function php_opcache.dl is the one that is configured under

zend_extension = php_opcache.dl
the php.ini image is appended

Comment: If you want to add more information to your question you should be able to edit the original.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.

the file opcache.ini was modified in the path /etc/php.d/opcache.ini and the option opcache.enable was set to 0 and that's it, it works correctly thank you very much.